# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot find built in speakers

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones

I cannot play the sound in my laptop speaker while increasing volume it produces sound only in headphones, not with the default built-in speaker.

Attached image below, while I'm checking for the output device, it shows me only built in headphones only.

Settings->Sound->Output Device

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpa4T.png

Comment: is anyone have the same issue ? kindly post it here

Comment: Many integrated sound cards/chips do not show distinct settings. What happens if you unplug the headphones?

Comment: yes, while an audio file is playing I'm unplugged it. And, force shutdown the system

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever opened the laptop? if so, check if the speakers are properly plugged in. If they are or you don't feel like taking out the screwdriver, check if it's enabled in the BIOS. Another solution might be to use a program to determine what connected devices are properly working.

Comment: Even if the speakers were unplugged internally, it should still show an option for the speakers, it just wouldn't output sound when they were selected.  Any speaker connection inside a laptop is usually just a wire going right to the physical speaker itself. Generally there's no sort of presence detection, as it is expected that the speakers will always be connected.

Physical connection issues definitely do happen sometimes, (when I got my laptop, it only had 1 speaker working due to a bent pin on the connector on the mobo,) but in this case, I don't think that's the issue the OP is having.